# Instantiating the templated function using variables

Tags: c++, templates, constants, template-specialization

I have three pointers within a class, each of which are instantiation of a templated structure. I am trying to retrieve either of them using a get<>() method whose return type differs accordingly.

```
//Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
class CBase {};
enum en {Aa = 1, Bb = 2, Cc = 3};
class A {
    public: 
    template<en dim>
    struct C : public CBase, boost::static_visitor<CBase *>{
        int x;
        C() {
          x = dim;
        }
        template <en t>
        CBase * operator()(C<t> *s) const {
          return s;
        }
    };

    C<Aa>* Aasd;
    C<Bb>* Bbsd;
    C<Cc>* Ccsd;
    std::map<en, boost::variant<C<Bb> *, C<Aa> *, C<Cc> * > > matrices;    

    A() {
        Aasd = new C<Aa>;
        Bbsd = new C<Bb>;
        Ccsd = new C<Cc>;
    matrices.insert(std::make_pair(Bb, Bbsd));
    matrices.insert(std::make_pair(Aa, Aasd));
    matrices.insert(std::make_pair(Cc, Ccsd));
   }

   template<en tt>
    C<tt>* get() {
     return static_cast<C<tt> *>(boost::apply_visitor(C<tt>(), matrices[tt]));   
    }

    ~A() {
     delete Aasd;
     delete Bbsd;
     delete Ccsd;
    }        
};

    template<>
    A::C<Aa>* A::get<Aa>() {
               return static_cast<C<Aa> *>(boost::apply_visitor(C<Aa>(), matrices[Aa]));
    }

    template<>
    A::C<Bb>* A::get<Bb>() {
               return static_cast<C<Bb> *>(boost::apply_visitor(C<Bb>(), matrices[Bb]));
    }

    template<>
    A::C<Cc>* A::get<Cc>() {
               return static_cast<C<Cc> *>(boost::apply_visitor(C<Cc>(), matrices[Cc]));
    }

int main()
{    
  A a;

  int i = 0;
  en samp = Aa;
  std::cout<<a.get<Aa>()->x<<std::endl; // This runs fine
  //std::cout<<a.get<samp>()->x<<std::endl; // This throws error: the value of 'samp' is not usable in a constant expression
  return 0;
}
```

I do understand that I need to specify a compile time constant to instantiate a template. However, in my case I would like to use a variable to retrieve either of the pointers. Any thoughts or suggestions on how to do that would be highly appreciated.

EDIT:

I am looking for alternate suggestions to retrieve the 'x' member of these 3 pointers Aasd, Bbsd, Ccsd as in the main function even if I have to completely remove the templates. It should be probably something like

```
en samp = Aa;
a.get(samp)->x = 6;
samp = Bb;
a.get(samp)->x = 5;
```

or

```
en samp = Aa;
a[samp]->x = 6;
samp = Bb;
a[samp]->x = 5;
```

Comment: If you know you need a compile time constant, how do you think using a variable could work?

Comment: Templates must be solved at compile-time, but your `samp` argument has value determined at run-time so can't be used at compile-time. Using templates  is a kind of programming for which execution is made at compile-time.

Comment: Apologies. May be I should have made this more clear in my question. I do understand that using a variable is not going to work for obvious reasons. All I am looking is for alternate suggestions to retrieve the pointers Aasd, Bbsd and Ccsd using a variable as in the main function.

Comment: @ZincFur, perhaps replace `Aa` with `runtime_function()` in the question to make it clear that it's not a constant

Comment: Retrieving the pointer will be possible, but the really big challenge is "where to store the result?". The return type of `get` cannot change at runtime. You'll need to think about the whole design here

Comment: @AaronMcDaid The struct C in actual contains a set of Eigen Matrices whose dimension are specified by the enum en. In my main function, based on what the user is inputting, I need to perform some matrix operations on the members of either of these pointer objects. Though the three pointer objects have matrix of different dim, after the matrix operations all of their results are going to be of same dimension. So, instead of using some ugly if else code, I thought of accessing the members as above. I ended up with the template code as above.

Comment: As you had rightly pointed out, I had been battling with run time return type. Any suggestions or ideas to look at. I would be happy to discard this and start from something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `x` into `CBase`, and then return `CBase *` from `get` instead of `C<T> *`. That will at least fix the problem with the return value, allowing the calling code to access `->x` easily.

Then you can have a simple method something like this (untested):

```
CBase* A::get(en x) {
    switch(x) {
        break; case Aa: return this->get<Aa>();
        break; case Bb: return this->get<Bb>();
        break; case Cc: return this->get<Cc>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Although, this might work only if I move x to the base class fom C. In my case, as I had explained in the comments under my question, the members of the C are all matrices and need to be instantiated through a template argument. In that case, again I have to downcast the CBase* to the particular derived class. This becomes the chicken and egg problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make `samp` constant:

```
const en samp;
```

EDIT: 
There is *why* it works:

Because

Non-type Template argument has to be constant expression (known at compile time)

proof:
N3337 14.3.2/1

> A **template-argument for a non-type**, non-template **template-parameter shall be one of**:
>
> ...
>
> - for a **non-type template-parameter** of integral or **enumeration type**, a converted **constant expression** of the type of the template-parameter; or
>
> ...

And when is enumeration type variable constant expression?

N3337 5.19/2:

> A conditional-expression is a core constant expression **unless it involves one of the following** as a potentially
>   evaluated subexpression
>
> ...
>
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) **unless it is applied to**
>
>   - a glvalue of integral or **enumeration type that refers to** a non-volatile **const object with a preceding
>       initialization**, **initialized with a constant expression**, or
>
> ...

and because in case of:

`const en samp = Aa`,  `samp` refers to const object initialized with constant expression

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just edited my question that I want to pass a variable and not a constant.

Comment: @ZincFur: If its a variable that it's not a compile time defined object and thus can't be used to instantiate a template. The only way the compiler can know that it is defined at compiler time is if you can not change it at run time.

Comment: @TobySpeight Better now?